# How to submit span values in a form using PHP?

Tags: php, html, forms, web

I have a HTML form contains span tags, and I want to submit the form with the span values using php. How can I do this?

Thanks..

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You definitely can't do it using pure php. There may be some javascript tricks but this is a bad idea.

Comment: @PeshrawH.Ahmed do you mean using span in the form is a bad idea?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is why? A span will contain either fixed content or generated content. Both of these could be created server side instead of transferring the data.

Comment: its fine to have a span in the form, just add a hidden element next to it and echo the value there too

Comment: No trying to submit a span value to form is a bad idea. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @PeshrawH.Ahmed  I am editing on a code and it is difficult to change the spans to inputs ..

Comment: Believe me trying to submit spans is more difficult :)

Comment: You never submit spans, you only ever submit form elements. You can have any HTML in a form, spans are fine.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you parse and process HTML/XML in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Spans are not form elements. Use a form element. If you don't want to use AJAX, that doesn't mean you can't use JS.

So, based on that, create some hidden form elements, and you can either echo the value in two places (one in your span, the other in the value attribute of the hidden field), or you can use JavaScript to pull the html out of the span and populate the form hidden element.

The PHP only method is the simplest and cleanest solution. Good luck!